# Prevent Loss of Carriage Returns from a MySQL LONGSTRING Value

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with loss of carriage returns in LONGSTRING values from MySQL. I do not know if the variable is holding the carriage returns or if they are being lost when I use `echo`. Here's a piece of my code. The code assumes that the MySQL query has already been run.

```
$longstringValue = $row['longstringValue']; // The value from the database has carriage returns...
echo $longstringValue                       // but they aren't present when I echo the variable.
```

What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line returns and carriage returns have no (visual) meaning in HTML, so if you need those breaks to render, run the **[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)** function at some point, as shown in the manual:

```
<?php
    echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

outputs

```
foo isn't<br /> bar
```

which renders as

> foo isn't 
>   bar

Comment: So carriage returns in a MySQL LONGSTRING value are `\n` when stored in a PHP variable?

Comment: @DavidB It depends on the input method. It could be `\r`, `\n`, or a combination of both; nl2br handles all of them, as noted in the manual.